# How to connect the raspberry pi to the internet with the internet from a pc (via an ethernet cable)

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, ethernet, connection, dhcp

excuse me I want to ask. I am still a beginner in raspberry pi. I have internet connection problems on the raspberry pi. I can remote raspberry with PC using ethernet. and my pc is also connected to the internet (hotspot from smartphone). I am trying to share internet network to my raspberry i can't connect to internet. I've also made the settings in /etc/dhcpcd.conf but still can't connect to the internet.

file etc/dhcpcd.conf as below:

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.2/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

I have also set the wifi property and have checked the wifi sharing option on the internet and sharing center.

anyone willing to help me???
I use Raspberry 3B, OS Raspbian Stretch, and on a PC using Windows 8.
is my dhcp having problems or something???

Comment: Does your windows 8 PC have any form of "internet connection sharing"?   Or can you connect the Pi straight to the smartphone's hotspot and leave the windows PC out of the picture?

Comment: I have set up my windows 8 pc to share the internet (ethernet) via internet properties. but my raspi still can't connect to the internet.
do you mean my raspi is connected to a smartphone hotspot?
because I need a PC to remote and build IoT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FIRST thing you should do is get rid of the static IP Address. (what you have is wrong, but it just makes it more difficult)

What you have to do is setup Interconnect Connection Sharing on the PC and enable DHCP.
This depends on OS, and is not a Pi Question.

If you do it correctly all you need to do is plugin the Ethernet cable.

Mind you if you have a hotspot you could just connect the Pi to this.

Comment: So what you mean is now I have to enable DHCP?
what else should I do about my raspberry pi can I get the internet from my pc?

Comment: @Zakkya.Arfi As noted in the answer, there is nothing to do on the RasPi if you use an unmodified (without static ip) image. Just connect it to the PC with an ethernet cable. Everything else has to be done on the MS Window$ PC and that's not a question to this site.